# How to access files in root directory of VPS from other shared hosting server?

Tags: php, remote-access, root-access

I have a VPS where I have uploaded some files in the root directory. I want to access those files on my website (developed in PHP) which is hosted on a shared server. Is it possible?

I have searched on internet but found nothing. Need some guidance.

thanks

Comment: Please define "root directory". Is it the root directory of the machine (the OS) or the web servers document root? If it's the root directory of the machine, then you need to either use SSH to connect to the machine with a user that has read permissions for the root directory, or you can create an API/proxy page on that machine that returns the files you need. The question is a bit unclear atm.

Comment: Sorry I am a newbie. Its root directory of apache webserver. OS is Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have 2 servers, one is the VPS and another is the shared hosting one.

You can access those files in a few ways.

- Open a SSH connection from your shared host to the VPS
- Setup a FTP server on the VPS and use a FTP connection from the shared hosting to the VPS
- Setup a PHP script (with some kind of authentication) to serve the files via an API.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me which method will be better for accessing videos on VPS and streaming them on shared hosting in this context?

Comment: If you want to stream them, you will need to expose the videos via an API, as the other methods aren't suitable for this.

Comment: Can you kindly suggest any PHP API?

Comment: You will need to write your own.